# Using find and exec inside while loop

Tags: bash, sed, git-bash

I've a .txt file which contains names of various files.

When I simply use a while loop it works fine,

```
while read -r name
do
  echo "$name"
done <fileNames.txt
```

But,
when I try to use find inside the loop, like this:

```
while read -r name
do
  find ./ -iname "$name" -exec sed -i '1s/^/NEW LINE INSERTED \n/' '{}' ';'
done < fileNames.txt
```

nothing happens!

If i use the find outside the loop like with a specific file name it does what it's supposed to do, I can also use it on all files with a specific file-type but it doesn't work inside the loop.

What am I doing wrong over here?

I'm trying to read file names from a file, search for it inside a folder recursively and then append a line in the beginning using sed.

Comment: Do you even need `find -exec`? Why can't you use sed directly? Do the names differ in case? Or are they somewhere in the directory tree?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes the files are at different locations in the tree.

Comment: And do you have GNU sed? For macOS sed, you need an argument for the `-i` option.

Comment: Or maybe whitespace in `fileNames.txt`? Can you add a representative sample from it?

Comment: @BenjaminW.it works fine outside of the loop, I'm using Git Bash on windows.

Comment: @BenjaminW. file with file names has no whitespaces at the end of each line, I'm using newline.

Comment: Are you missing the `-e` flag to sed?  You are specifing a "script" but not telling sed about it.

Comment: Does `fileNames.txt` use DOS line endings?

Comment: Also, just because you can echo the value of `$name` doesn't necessarily mean there is a file with that name in the current directory.

Comment: @chepner I just created it manually in notepad++

Comment: @chepner  find works outside of the loop .

Comment: @7Reeds I don't think -e applies here, it's just one command inside the loop

Comment: @AamirYousuf, nodepad++ supports either DOS or UNIX line endings, so I don't think you answered the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy DOS endings, I'm on windows.

Comment: Try add `-print` to the `find` command so you can be sure it's finding something.

Comment: Try using `dos2unix fileNames.txt`, see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Barmar dos2unix didn't help either, using print prints all file and folder names with the path, preceding with './'

Comment: Can you create a minimal `fileNames.txt` that has the problem you encounter so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript` will log each `find` command it runs, so you can see if that command looks like what you expect, and try running it yourself by hand. Note that carriage returns present in DOS newlines look like `$'\r'` in that log output.

Comment: @BenjaminW. it's a minimal file that I'm using before running the script for my final purpose, it has 5 lines with each line like demo.txt. I'm sorry should I paste it all in the question or is there a better way of sharing it?

Comment: @AamirYousuf, ...editing the question to include the `xtrace` logs (as from `bash -x yourscript`, or `set -x` in your script), as I described in the immediately-prior comment, would be a good place to start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Getting the correct output on including xtrace and I think dos2unix unix helped. I converted using the command this time, earlier I was just trying in notepad++. Thank for the help.

Comment: @BenjaminW. i think dos2unix helped, earlier I had just tried converting in notepad++. Not sure what was wrong with the text file. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use xargs instead to capture the results of find

```
while read -r name
do
  find ./ -iname "$name" |xargs sed -i '1s/^/NEW LINE INSERTED \n/'
done <fileNames.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix any problems, but it *introduces* a massive security hole. If someone creates a file with `$'\n/etc/passwd\n'` as a subset of its name, this `xargs` command will tell `sed` to modify `/etc/passwd`. The `find ... -exec` approach used by the OP's code is much safer.

Comment: See the warnings in [the *Actions in Bulk* section of UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) about `xargs`, and [BashPitfalls #56](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0).

Comment: Security wasn't listed as an issue, nor did he mention this would be used on files created by others, let alone untrusted people.

It makes no sense to use sed to modify a bunch of files in place -- especially something that looks like adding a header row to a bunch of data files -- unless he already knows what the files are.

Comment: This works but a bit slow, my original script is working now, I created a new text file and used dos2unix command to convert it. I think something was wrong with my text file. Thanks @KyleBanerjee And yes, security wasn't a concern here, I was the one running the script.

Comment: Security is always a concern, I'd say.

Comment: @KyleBanerjee, ...the whole point of the site is to be a teaching resource. If we're teaching practices that are only safe when you're never operating on uploaded/received/3rd-party-provided files, it's only reasonable to provide a warning alongside (if there's even enough value to the practice to be worth teaching at all) -- otherwise, how is someone supposed to know that the practice they're reading about is dangerous?

Comment: @AamirYousuf You can *think* you know what something is or contains, but gracefully handling cases where expectations and reality differ is critical. Worst data loss event I've been present for was in a script operating on files that "couldn't ever" have names that weren't just 20 hex characters -- until a bug in a C library used by a new program generating those files dumped random garbage from memory into a buffer used for the filename. Pure bug, no malicious intent, but that buffer contained a whitespace-surrounded `*`, and the result was loss of TB of backups.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The warning is well placed, and I really should have brought it up myself for the exact reasons you mention. I was trying to keep things simple. AamirYousuf, the locate command is much faster than find and is probably the reason for the poor performance you have. However, if these files are really new, you'd want to run updatedb before running your script.